# How can I run a python file inside another python file?

Tags: python

I'm having a difficult time trying to run a python file within another python file as a module. The program I am trying to run inside the other python file works fine on its own. However, when I import it as a module it does not do anything and does not even give me an error code.
This is the first code. The file name is speech2text.py

```
def mainprogram():

    import os
    import sys
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = r"C:\Users\taiki\PycharmProjects\startup\stelarvision-280712-c709366612cc.json"
    filepath = "./"
    output_filepath = "./"
    bucketname = "stelarvision2020"
    sys.path.append("/users/taiki/appdata/local/packages/pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0/localcache/local-packages/python38/site-packages")
    sys.path.append("/Users/taiki/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages")
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    import wave
    from google.cloud import storage


    def stereo_to_mono(audio_file_name):
        sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_file_name)
        sound = sound.set_channels(1)
        sound.export(audio_file_name, format="wav")


    def frame_rate_channel(audio_file_name):
        with wave.open(audio_file_name, "rb") as wave_file:
            frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
            channels = wave_file.getnchannels()
            return frame_rate, channels


    def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

        blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)


    def delete_blob(bucket_name, blob_name):
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

        blob.delete()


    def google_transcribe(audio_file_name):
        file_name = filepath + audio_file_name
        frame_rate, channels = frame_rate_channel(file_name)

        if channels > 1:
            stereo_to_mono(file_name)

        bucket_name = bucketname
        source_file_name = filepath + audio_file_name
        destination_blob_name = audio_file_name

        upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)

        gcs_uri = 'gs://' + bucketname + '/' + audio_file_name
        transcript = ''

        client = speech.SpeechClient()
        audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

        config = types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz=frame_rate,
            language_code='en-US',
            enable_automatic_punctuation=True)

        operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
        response = operation.result(timeout=10000)

        for result in response.results:
            transcript += result.alternatives[0].transcript

        delete_blob(bucket_name, destination_blob_name)
        return transcript


    def write_transcripts(transcript_filename, transcript):
        f = open(output_filepath + transcript_filename, "w+")
        f.write(transcript)
        f.close()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        audio_file_name = "sample_music.wav"
        transcript = google_transcribe(audio_file_name)
        transcript_filename = audio_file_name.split('.')[0] + '.txt'
        write_transcripts(transcript_filename, transcript)
mainprogram()
```

This is the second python file

```
def run():
    import speech2text
    speech2text.mainprogram()

run()
```

When I execute the second file it doesn't do anything..

Comment: the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part can be executed only we you run `speech2text.py` directly. so please make the code as anothe function body, then run `speech2text.mainprogram.main()`

Comment: Don't use `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 1):

The part `if __name__ == "__main__":` is only executed when you execute that script directly, i.e. `python speech2text.py`.

To make your program work, delete that if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your python files is a little bit strange. It's better to `import sys` and `import os` at the head of the file rather than `import` something in a `class`.
Also, your indent has problem. In my opinion, you'd better download a nice IDE like pycharm to automatically check your syntax errors.

Comment: The indentation seems fine as far as I can tell. Plus, OP said there was no error message. That being said, the structure is really not following any Python conventions. But that's not what the question was about.

Comment: Look at the end of the first file, `mainprogram()`  has no indentation here. If he or she wants to call the `mainprogram()` function in the second file, he does not have to add `if __name__ == "__main__":` and belows. That's actually the cause of the problem

Comment: @debug Thank you I'll get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

First, you should put the import outside the function, as it would be more conventional. You should also check if two files are in the same folder.

Second, this part will not work if you call it outside

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        audio_file_name = "sample_music.wav"
        transcript = google_transcribe(audio_file_name)
        transcript_filename = audio_file_name.split('.')[0] + '.txt'
        write_transcripts(transcript_filename, transcript)
```

this one is used to indicate that don't automatically run when got called from another program, which basically you are doing now.

Third, the last line `mainprogram()` in the first file, not sure what you mean here. You have already have a command to run a function in the second program `speech2text.mainprogram()` after importing.

Maybe you only have done wrong in one part not all 3 that I am suggesting, so please do try and test!

Comment: Thank you I'll try fixing it